# Video Lens Only Displays up to 100 Local Videos

Tags: 12.04, video, lenses

The video lens only displays 100 of 'My Videos', even though I have hundreds more.
If I add more to the folder, that gets displayed, but others are removed.

Is there any way to increase the limit, to display them all?

I really would love to use this feature, but I would require it to index my entire video folder for me to browse using this lens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video lens is coded to display a maximum of 100 results in its searches of local files.  If there is no search terms entered, then it will display the first 100 local videos it finds.  With search terms, it will display the first 100 videos matching the search terms that it finds.

The maximum limit is there for reasons of performance.  It is also more difficult for users to find what they are looking for  large numbers of results rather than try to reduce the number of results by using more specific search terms.

That being said, to increase the maximum number of results being displayed:

1. In a terminal, enter the following to edit the source code of the video lens:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/lib/unity-lens-video/unity-lens-video
   ```

   You will need to enter your password to edit this file.
2. In the file, find line 220:

   ```
   if video_counter < 100:
   ```

   (or press **CTRL+F** and search for **100**)
3. Change 100 to a larger number ( e.g. 500) and save the file
4. Log out and log back in again. The video lens should now display a larger number of local files.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. PS: The search function did not work with me previously. All it did was search amongst the videos displayed in the list. Perhaps an update fixed that. Regardless, I thought it would be nice to expand it anyway.